# Como arrumar a tabela para que foto e informações fiquem na mesma linha?

Tags: html, css, html5, table, tabela-html

Preciso que a imagem e informações do imóvel contidos na tabela fiquem na mesma altura, mas não sei como arrumar.

Seguem as fotos de como está e como eu queria:

[image: Como está no momento]

[image: Como eu queria]

Segue o código:

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
@font-face {
    font-family: 'FonteLogo';
 src: url("../fonts/GLCBaskerville.ttf");
}

/*******************************CSS DAS MEDIDAS PRINCIPAIS DO SITE*/

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .container{
        max-width: 790px;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
    .container{
        max-width: 790px;
    }
}

body {
    margin-top: 10px;
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #727E55;   
}

.container, .container-fluid {
    background-color: #fFF;   
}

.row {
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 3px;
}

[class*="col-"], header, footer, aside, section, div[role="main"] {
    margin-top: 0;
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    padding-left: 3px;
    padding-right: 3px;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    background-color: rgba(86,61,124,.15);
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    border: 1px solid rgba(86,61,124,.2);
}

div[role="main"], footer {
    background-color: #fff;
    height: auto;
}

header, .masthead, .img-rolante {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

/*******************************CSS DA TABELA*/

.bloco {
    align-items: center;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

.info {
 font-family: Verdana;
 color: #829951;
 font-size: 2;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-align: left;
    height: auto; /*25px*/
}

.info a,
.info a:hover,
.info a:active,
.info a:focus {
 text-decoration: none;
 font-family: Verdana;
 color: #829951;
 font-size: 2;
    font-weight: 700;
}

.descricao {
    height: auto;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-size: 2;
    color: #697052;
    text-align: justify;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
    
<head>
    <title>LoremIpsum</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">    
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">  
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- CSS do Index -->
    <link href="css/imoveis.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/geral.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">   
</head> 

<body>    
    <div class="container">         
        
        <header class="row"> 
            <div class="masthead">
                <div class="img-header">
                    <a class="logo" href="#">LoremIpsum.Com</a> <span class="icones"><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span></a> <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span></a></span>
                </div>                 
            </div>
        </header>    

        <div class="row">           

            <div role="main" class="col-md-12">    
                <div class="separador" style="margin-bottom: 5px"></div>
                
                <div class="table-responsive">
                    <tbody class="bloco" align="center">
                        <tr><td style="height:140px; width:170px">
                            <table style="border:1px solid #B0C088" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr><td align="center"><a name="tm226" href="#"><img src="https://img.r7.com/external_images?dimensions=348x196&url=https://vtb.r7.com/396768/2019/12/08/5ded5b634b495564c400008e/9fef53c01c1c4926839c729d6dc1288b__CR7_FA_0812_RODRIGOCUIDADASOVELHAS_thumb_thumb.jpg" width="200"></a></td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                            </td>
                            
                            <td style="width:600px">
                                <table style="width:585px">
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                        <td class="info" width="135">ID: XXYYY</td>
                                            
                                        <td class="info" width="200">Área: XX hectares</td>
                                            
                                        <td class="info" width="250"><a href="mapatm226.htm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span> XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX - XX</a>
                                        </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        
                                        <tr>
                                            <td class="descricao" colspan="3" height="90" width="585"><p><span style="font-weight:700; color:#FF6600">ATENÇÃO!</span> <span style="font-weight:700; color:#829951">Oportunidade!</span> Sitio com 32 hectares (320.000 m²) a Venda em São Bento do Sapucaí, região da Serra da Mantiqueira, em local de rara beleza e total privacidade sem estar isolada, lindos recantos e vista (360º) panorâmica para a Pedra do Baú, são os cartões postais desta propriedade. Terreno com ótima topografia, muitos platôs, terras de cultura, pastos bem formados e rico em água. Ótima localização e fácil acesso, fica apenas 3 km da cidade. Oportunidade única para investir em uma área de beleza cinematográfica, com alto potencial para empreendimentos voltados ao lazer e ao turismo.</p></td>
                                        </tr>
                                        
                                        <tr><td align="center" colspan="3" height="25" width="585">
                                                <table style="border-collapse: collapse" width="585">
                                                    <tbody>
                                                        <tr><td width="585">
                                                            <table width="585">
                                                                <tbody>
                                                                    <tr><td class="info" width="135">R$0.000.000,00</td>
                                                                        
                                                                    <td class="info" width="200"><a href="mailto:contato@terrasdamantiqueira.com?subject=TMXXX - XX hectares - XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX-XX - LoremIpsum.Com"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span> Clique Aqui</a></td>
                                                                        
                                                                    <td class="info" width="250"><span class="  glyphicon glyphicon-phone-alt"></span> (XX) XXXX.XXXX</td>
                                                                    </tr>
                                                                </tbody>
                                                            </table>
                                                            </td></tr>
                                                    </tbody>
                                                </table>
                                            </td></tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </div>
                
                <div class="separador"></div>
                
            </div>
            
        </div>
        
        <footer class="row">
            
                        
            <div class="img-footer">
            </div>
            
            <p style="font-size: 8px; margin-top: 5px; margin-bottom:2px"> <img style="margin-left: 10px; margin-right: 10px" src="https://img.r7.com/external_images?dimensions=348x196&url=https://vtb.r7.com/396768/2019/12/08/5ded5b634b495564c400008e/9fef53c01c1c4926839c729d6dc1288b__CR7_FA_0812_RODRIGOCUIDADASOVELHAS_thumb_thumb.jpg" width="200" /> <!--<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone" style="margin-left: 10px; margin-right: 10px"></span> +55 12 3971.1150 --> <span class="linkt1">TERMOS DE USO</span> Web Design &amp; Development by <a class="linkt1" href="mailto:contato@terrasdamantiqueira.com">LoremIpsum.Com</a> © 2003 | All 
      rights reserved | <span class="linkt1">CRECI SP XXXXX 
      - CRECI MG XXXXX</span> </p>
            
            <p style="font-size: 11px; margin-bottom:3px"> Encontre seu Imóvel na <a class="linkt2" href="terrasdamantiqueira.com">LoremIpsum.Com</a>
            </p>
            
            <p style="font-size:8px; margin-bottom:1px">
                <a href="#" class="linkt1">CASAS A VENDA</a> | 
                <a href="#" class="linkt1">CHÁCARAS A VENDA</a> |
                <a href="#" class="linkt1">SÍTIOS A VENDA</a> |
                <a href="#" class="linkt1">FAZENDAS A VENDA</a> |
                <a href="#" class="linkt1">POUSADAS A VENDA</a> |
                <a href="#" class="linkt1">TERRENOS A VENDA</a>
            </p>
            
            <p style="font-size:11px"><a href="#" class="link3">CLIQUE AQUI</a> e Cadastre seu Imóvel a Venda conosco</p>
            
        </footer>  
        
    </div>    

    <!-- jQuery (necessario para os plugins Javascript Bootstrap) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Agradeço a ajuda desde já!

Answer (score 1):

Então, sua dúvida é bem simples, se eu entendi direito o que você precisa.

Tudo o que você precisa fazer é colocar a td que contém o seu texto, na mesma tr que contém a td em que está sua imagem.

Assim:

```
<tr>
   <td align="center">
      <a name="tm226" href="#">
        <img src="imagem/tm22600/tm22600.jpg">
      </a>
   </td>
   <td class="descricao" colspan="3" height="90" width="585">
      <p>
         <span style="font-weight:700; color:#FF6600">ATENÇÃO!</span> <span style="font-weight:700; color:#829951">Oportunidade!</span> Sitio com 32 hectares (320.000 m²) a Venda em São Bento do Sapucaí, região da Serra da Mantiqueira, em local de rara beleza e total privacidade sem estar isolada, lindos recantos e vista (360º) panorâmica para a Pedra do Baú, são os cartões postais desta propriedade. Terreno com ótima topografia, muitos platôs, terras de cultura, pastos bem formados e rico em água. Ótima localização e fácil acesso, fica apenas 3 km da cidade. Oportunidade única para investir em uma área de beleza cinematográfica, com alto potencial para empreendimentos voltados ao lazer e ao turismo.
      </p>
   </td>
</tr>
```

Até mais o/

Answer (score 1):

Ao invés de tabela, eu te recomendaria usar flexbox (aqui tem uma referência bem boa https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Tu colocava um container com a imagem na esquerda e o todo em uma div na direita

```
<div class="container">
    <img src="...">
    <div class="content">
        ...
    </div>
</div
```

O container teria algo como:

```
.container {
    width: X; //conforme o teu layout, ou 100%...
    display:flex;
    align-items: flex-start;
}
```

Depois a imagem e a div com o conteúdo teriam algo como:

```
img {
    width: Y; //Tamanho da imagem
}
div.content {
    flex: 1; //Usará o restante da largura do container pra si
}
```